# cakephp - one framework, a few apps on localhost subdomain

Tags: cakephp, subdomain, localhost, structure, directory

How to prepare CakePHP framework to work for many apps in one CakePHP framework?
I want prepare structure folders like this:

1. app1/
2. app2/
3. app3/
4. cake/
5. vendors/
6. plugins/
7. index.php

I would like using http://app1.localhost/ do running app from app1/ folder?
It's possible?

Comment: Great idea for testing CakePHP plugins!

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need to do is configure the `app/webroot/index.php` file of every individual app correctly to point to the correct `ROOT`/`cake` folder. The rest is Apache virtual host configuration to point the subdomains to the right app folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running XAMPP but I'm assuming you're running something similar on your machine.  Anyway, go into your `apache\conf` folder and open up the `httpd.conf` file.  XAMPP has a file called `apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` that is better for adding Virtual Hosts.

So you'd want to enter the appropriate directives like so...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/path-to-your-app-webroot-folder-no-trailing-slash"
    ServerName app.localhost
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/app.localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/app.localhost-access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:/path-to-your-app-webroot-folder-no-trailing-slash">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all  
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Furthermore, if you're on Windows XP, you'll want to make an entry in your `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file of `127.0.0.1 app.localhost` to resolve the sub-domain.  That should get the job done.